# Collection view doesn't resize when new items are added

Tags: ios, swift

I have a vertical collection view inside custom table view cell:

```
private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout).prepareForAutoLayout()
        
        collectionView.register(StudyDirectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: StudyDirectionCell.identifier)
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return collectionView
    }()

 override func prepare(withViewModel viewModel: PreparableViewModel?) {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel as? ActualScreenModels.Cell, case .directions(let model) = viewModel else { return }
        
        self.bachelor = model.bachelor
        self.college = model.college
        prepareViews()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

   @objc private func handleShowMore() {
        if selectedSegment == "bachelor" {
            rowsToDisplay = bachelor
        } else {
            rowsToDisplay = college
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
 
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(countDynamicHeight())
        }
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

private func prepareCollectionView() {
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16)
            make.top.equalTo(segmentedControl.snp.bottom).offset(25)
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
            make.height.equalTo(countDynamicHeight())
        }

        
        cellLabel.text = "Actual.StudyDirections".localized.uppercased()
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.reloadData()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .directionsCellBackground
    }

extension StudyDirectionsCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width: CGFloat = contentView.frame.size.width*343.0/375.0
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width*126.0/343.0)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowsToDisplay.count
    }
    
    func countDynamicHeight() -> CGFloat {
        let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width-32
        let height: CGFloat = width*126.0/343.0
        let rowsCount = ceil(CGFloat(rowsToDisplay.count))
        let totalSeparationHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(max(0, (rowsCount - 1)) * 10)
        let collectionViewHeight = height * rowsCount + totalSeparationHeight
        return collectionViewHeight
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

extension StudyDirectionsCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: StudyDirectionCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? StudyDirectionCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        cell.configure(with: rowsToDisplay[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

When I click show more button two new items (rows) are added to the collection view, but it doesn't resize (expand)

As you can see I'm trying not only reload data after click expand button (which I guess is enough) but also
`collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()`

and even once more add height constraint:
 `collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in        make.height.equalTo(countDynamicHeight()) }`
I set breakpoint to the `countDynamicHeight` method and it is called every time I press the `show more` button. But my collection view doesn't resize... I don't know maybe it is because collection view is inside custom table view cell?

Comment: Better approach is set some flag for `bachelor/collage` value and reload the `tableViewCell` it self.

Comment: Like @NighWatcher is saying: The tableView doesn't have any information that it should resize the cell, so you need to send that information to the tableView